# Como hacer un respaldo de la base de datos desde terminal?

Tags: sql-server, linux, tsql

Tengo una base de datos en MS SQL Server 2017 express, en Ubuntu 16.04, la estoy administrando don `DBeaver` y no encuentro una opción para hacer un backup, he intendo con terminal y no funciona:

```
$tsql -S localhost -U SA

BACKUP DATABASE prolo TO DISK = '/home/user/bakup'
go
```

pero no funciona dice que hay un error de sintaxis.

Answer (score 3):

Al parecer te hace falta especificar la extensión al  nombre del archivo de respaldo en el  comando BACKUP DATABASE:

```
BACKUP DATABASE prolo TO DISK = '/home/user/bakup.bak'
```

Adicionalmente es probable que tengas que especificar opciones adicionales para especificar que no comprima el respaldo puesto que la [versión express](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017) no soporta compresión por ejemplo:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [base] TO  DISK = N'/var/opt/mssql/data/file.bak' 
WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'TSQLV4-Full Database Backup',
 SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, NO_COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10;
GO
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]